# Passing two arguments through URL

Tags: python, django

I have this link in my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'listings:listing_detail' name_initials=university.name_initials l_slug=list.l_slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">See More</a>
```

Here are my app urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from listings import views

app_name = 'listings'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.UniversityListView.as_view(),name='universities'),
    url(r'^(?P<l_slug>[-\w]+)$',views.ListingView.as_view(),name='listing_detail'),
]
```

And here is my view associated with it:

```
class UniversityHomePageView(ListView):
    model = Listing
    context_object_name = 'listing'
    template_name_suffix = '_university_homepage'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['university'] = University.objects.all()
        context['company'] = Company.objects.all()
        return context
```

I want this link to go to the the listings page however it is giving me an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /tu/
Reverse for 'listing_detail' with keyword arguments '{'name_initials': '', 'l_slug': 'stafford-apartments'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<name_initials>\\w+)/(?P<l_slug>[-\\w]+)$']
```

I am not really sure what to do. I think I need to be passing two variables to the view but if what I am doing isn't correct then I am a little lost on what to do, I have read the docs but don't quite no what to do still.

Using Django 1.11.

Comment: In your context, `university` is a full queryset, but you reference `university.name_initials` as if it name_initials were a field on the model. It could be a manager method, but I doubt this. It appears that empty string gets passed, but I cannot say why. (and we don't know what's in urls.py)

Comment: @AlanSE just updated to show urls

Comment: isn't listing_detail missing a kwarg for `name_initials` in urls.py? I'd expect a similar pattern as for l_slug